# DDD entities gaining access to DAO

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

I have created a Domain Driven Design domain model but am having trouble with state. I need to be able to scale up my application by creating multiple instances and therefore (under certain situations, not all) cannot hold state in my model. It still seems like the state should be retrieved via the model and I would therefore like to have some way of querying the database (via a service, dao) from my model to make sure the state is synchronised between all instances.

Does anybody know the accepted way of ding this, or is it that stateless apps are not appropriate for DDD?

Cheers

Comment: What is the client type, for which you need to have state in various instances? Is it a REST based HTTP client?

Comment: @Manish Maheshwari Yes, there is a REST client which will discover an instances of the service (depending on how many have been made available) which many not be the previous service instance

Comment: If you are more precise with your example perhaps would could answer your question better... care to explain that part of the domain you are having a hard time to model?

Comment: @JLove In DDD web applications, you typically don't hold a reference to an Aggregate Root for longer than a short applicative transaction, so I fail to see what you call "hold state in the model". Besides, this has little to do with the application being consumed in a stateless way from the outside (REST).

Answer (score 0):

Stateless apps are the **preferred way**.

Its acceptable to persist/retrieve the state using one of the below techniques:

1. If you have (or can have) one of the in-memory caching services like
   [memcached](http://memcached.org/), or an in-memory data grid like HazelCast, you can use those for storing the state. Any instance can save/retrive the state based upon some unique clientId or sessionId in one of these stores.
2. In the database.
3. This is not possible with REST clients, but for completeness: For UI
   clients, you might retrieve the state from HTTP cookies, thus passing the burden of keeping the state to the client.

This is certainly not a comprehensive list, but is a list of commonly used techniques.